# Extract number from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm using this code:

```
s = line.match( /ABCD(\d{4})/ ).values_at( 1 )[0]
```

To extract numbers from strings like:

```
ABCD1234
ABCD1235
ABCD1236
```

etc.

It works, but I wonder what other alternative I have to to this in Ruby?

My code:

```
ids = [] 
someBigString.lines.each {|line|
   ids << line.match( /ABCD(\d{4})/ ).values_at( 1 )[0] 
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
a.map {|x| x[/\d+/]}
```

Comment: What's the semantic of `map` how should I understand it? I understand `collect` but I have always had trouble understanding map.

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, Enumerable#map is a synonym for Enumerable#collect

Comment: FYI: If you have numbers split up by other characters, this only grabs the first "chunk" of numbers. So for '123ABC456', it'll only grab '123'. Use something like line.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') if you want to get all the numbers.

Comment: should also clarify that this works on an enumerable such as an array, not a string as the title is asking

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for String

Comment: You don't call map on the string. In the example `a` is an array of strings and `x` is the string. So it's `[/\d+/]` that you need to apply to a string.

Comment: See my answer below for the fastest solution.

Comment: @GarryGomez  OP is looping over an array of  lines of strings in his example.

Answer (score 218):

There are many Ruby ways as per http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125709

1. `line.scan(/\d/).join('')`
2. `line.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '')`
3. `line.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')`
4. `line.tr("^0-9", '')`
5. `line.delete("^0-9")`
6. `line.split(/[^\d]/).join`
7. `line.gsub(/\D/, '')`

Try each on you console.

Also check the benchmark report in that post.

Comment: line.delete("^0-9") is the fastest as per the link

Comment: Delete is fastest as indicated in my answer below.

Comment: If you need the result to be `to_i` and `to_f` compatible, then I would recommend not removing the  decimal point `.`, by adding it to the included characters ex: `delete('^.0-9')`

Answer (score 68):

there is even simpler solution

```
line.scan(/\d+/).first
```

Comment: this only returns the first match of consecutive numbers from the the string. So `'ab123cd45'.scan(/\d+/).first` would just return `12`

Comment: truly terrible solution, how does this have so many upvotes

Answer (score 20):

The simplest and fastest way is use regular expression to parse the integers out from the string.

```
str = 'abc123def456' 

str.delete("^0-9")
=> "123456"

str.tr("^0-9","")
=> "123456"
```

Comparing benchmarks on a long string with some of the other solutions provided here, we can see `tr` is fastest with `delete` close 2nd.

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 2 
string = [*'a'..'z'].concat([*1..1_000_000].map(&:to_s)).shuffle.join

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('scan') do
    n.times {string.scan(/\d/).join}
  end
  x.report('gsub') do
    n.times {string.gsub(/[^\d]/,"")}
  end
  x.report('gsub2') do
    n.times {string.gsub(/\D/, '')}
  end
  x.report('tr') do
    n.times {string.tr("^0-9","")}
  end
  x.report('delete') do
    n.times {string.delete('^0-9')}
  end
  x.report('split') do
    n.times {string.split(/[^\d]/).join}
  end
end

Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
scan     3.509973   0.187274   3.697247 (  3.717773)
gsub     0.229568   0.002790   0.232358 (  0.233961)
gsub2    0.307728   0.013435   0.321163 (  0.390262)
tr       0.021395   0.000223   0.021618 (  0.022297)
delete   0.021290   0.002280   0.023570 (  0.024365)
split    0.284935   0.010274   0.295209 (  0.299865)
--------------------------------- total: 4.591165sec

             user     system      total        real
scan     3.146615   0.126009   3.272624 (  3.281860)
gsub     0.211263   0.001515   0.212778 (  0.213170)
gsub2    0.208482   0.000424   0.208906 (  0.209339)
tr       0.015228   0.000086   0.015314 (  0.015387)
delete   0.015786   0.000128   0.015914 (  0.016050)
split    0.205096   0.002736   0.207832 (  0.208380)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
your_input = "abc1cd2"
your_input.split(//).map {|x| x[/\d+/]}.compact.join("").to_i
```

This should work.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: This feels inefficient `"abc1cd2".split(/[^\d]/).join.to_i` gets to the same result, in a more direct way. However, as mentioned in the previous comment, it's hard to comment without any commentary on your assumptions and how you are trying to solve the problem. However this does bring up the question on if the numbers are separated: should they be concatenated or summed?  The answer could be `[1, 2].inject(:+) => 3` instead of `[1, 2].join => 12` depending on how you choose to handle that case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution may be to write:

```
myString = "sami103"
myString.each_char{ |c| myString.delete!(c) if c.ord<48 or c.ord>57 } #In this case, we are deleting all characters that do not represent numbers.
```

Now, if you type

```
myNumber = myString.to_i #or myString.to_f
```

This should return a

Comment: In general, using ordinals like this is a little dangerous as a general solution in the age of multi-byte character sets. Depending on the characters you are dealing with and the character set, things could get different results in different locales.

Answer (score 0):

number strings could be decimals and / or negative.  Therefore:

```rb
  [string.chr == "-" ? "-" : nil, string.delete("^.0-9")].compact.inject(:+)
```

This leverages the [`chr` method](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-chr) to check if the string starts with a negative symbol `-`.  then it strips everything except digits and decimals then prepends the `-` if it was there originally.

this allows for chaining with the `to_i` and `to_f` methods.

- `compact` removes the nil from the array, if it wasn't negative
- `inject(:+)` flattens the array back into a string based on the order of the contents of the array

### If Fractions are also and issue

```rb
[
  chr == "-" ? "-" : nil,
  gsub(%r{[^./0-9[:space:]]}, "")
    .gsub(%r{[[:space:]]*(?<numerator>\d+)[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*(?<denominator>\d+)}) do
      Regexp.last_match.named_captures.then do |capture_hash|
        Rational(capture_hash.fetch("numerator", 0), capture_hash.fetch("denominator", 1)).to_f.to_s.delete_prefix('0')
      end
    end
].compact.inject(:+).strip
```

#### This is assuming 'proper fractions'

This version adds `/` and `[[:space:]]`to the exception list to indicate where the division is going to occur and to allow us to leverage spaces for determining the size of the fractions.

`gsub(%r{[[:space:]]*(?<numerator>\d+)[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*(?<denominator>\d+)})` is a regex that looks for:

1. `[[:space:]]*` -> zero or more spaces
2. `(?<numerator>\d+)` a group of digits for the numerator
3. `[[:space:]]*` -> zero or moere spaces
4. `(?<denominator>\d+)` a group of digits for the denominator

`Regexp.last_match.named_captures` gives us a hash of the named capture groups and the matched values:

```rb
"3 1 / 2 cups".gsub(%r{[^./0-9[:space:]]}, "").gsub(%r{[[:space:]]*(?<numerator>\d+)[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*(?<denominator>\d+)}) do
  Regexp.last_match.named_captures # => {"numerator"=>"1", "denominator"=>"2" }
end
```

With this hash we can `fetch` and set default values so that `Rational` will always resolve to 0 if the numerator and denominator are not found.

`.to_f.to_s.delete_prefix('0')` is where the assumption that the fraction will always have a smaller numerator than denominator.  This portion of the code converts the fraction into a float and then a string, after that if strips the leading zero from the string which is expected to be a zero. If it isn't it should be obvious in the output and you can modify accordingly to add the float to the previous number.

```rb
Rational(1, 2).to_f                         # => 0.5
Rational(1, 2).to_f.to_s                    # => "0.5"
Rational(1, 2).to_f.to_s.delete_prefix('0') # => ".5"
```

[delete_prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string) has a benchmark close to the fastest `[1..-1]` but is a lot more readable so I chose it for that reason.

then finally we have a `strip` to clean up any leading or trailing whitespace.

NOTE: if you are tacking on the `to_i` or `to_f` methods here you don't need `strip`, as they are not picky about the whitespace and parse the numbers just fine without it.  So, you could wind up with something like this that tacks those methods on for you, if you want a method:

```rb
def numberize(with: :strip)
  raise ArgumentError, "with: #{with} is not a valid argument" unless with.in?(%i[strip to_i to_f])

  [
    chr == "-" ? "-" : nil,
    gsub(%r{[^./0-9[:space:]]}, "")
      .gsub(%r{[[:space:]]*(?<numerator>\d+)[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*(?<denominator>\d+)}) do
        Regexp.last_match.named_captures.with_indifferent_access.then do |capture_hash|
          Rational(capture_hash.fetch(:numerator, 0), capture_hash.fetch(:denominator, 1)).to_f.to_s.delete_prefix('0')
        end
      end
  ].compact.inject(:+).send(with)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

To extract number part from a string use the following:

```
str = 'abcd1234'
/\d+/.match(str).try(:[], 0)
```

It should return `1234`

Comment: You don't need `match` or `try` if you use this string matching syntax `str[/\d+/]`

Comment: also `.try` is not core ruby so this answer fails without `active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb` or rails