# get numerical part of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the numerical part of a result.

For example I have **"1.23 %"** and I want to get "1.23".

Does anyone have any idea about how can I do?

Thanks !

Comment: RAJ's answer is right for the example you provided. If you also want to remove things for like currency `$35` or large numbers with commas "123,456", just remove anything that isn't a digit or dot. `number_string.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract number from string in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640819/extract-number-from-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very easily, just need to use `to_f` method.

```
"1.23 %".to_f
=> 1.23
```

As Vahid said, for getting string version in result, you can further use `to_s`

```
"1.23 %".to_f.to_s
=> "1.23"
```

Comment: And also using `to_s` to get string version.`"1.23 %".to_f.to_s`

Comment: Thank you all ! In the end, if I'm working with a string, Vahid and Raj's method is great, and if I'm working with a standard number on excel, Ben Lee's works like a charm. Cheers !