# How to find a devise user by user_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I am currently enrolled in a `TreeHouse tutorial` for `Ruby on Rails` but as I follow along I am modifying some things that are being done to my own liking.

However, I have come to a problem that has me scratching my head.

What I would like to do is get the `user_id` of a user's `show` page. What the tutorial has done is create a new field for `devise`, `profile_name`.

I skipped this step, because i did not want my users to be identified that way. I wanted them to be identified by their `"user_id" + "first_name" + "last_name"`. In doing what the tutorial did, what he achieved was that he created custom routes for each individual user signed up to his site by the use of their unique `profile_name`. In my case it would be `"user_id" + "first_name" + "last_name"`. If someone could shed some light on this and hopefully also point me to a resource I could potentially learn more on this subject I would really appreciate it.

Thanks for reading and have a nice day! :D

---

This is what they had in the tutorial.

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
    //@user = User.find_by_user_id(params[:id]) //my code that I thought would work
    if @user
        @statuses = @user.statuses.all
        render action: :show
    else
        render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end
end
```

**ROUTES FILE**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/:id', to: 'profile#show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to have slashes to separate your id/first_name/last_name params. The reason being is that let's say someone's identifier ends up as 105johnsmith - well, how do you know that their first name hasn't been entered as 5joh, and their last name as nsmith, leaving their id as 10, rather than 105? You don't.

However, if you want to assume that the first digits of the identifier are in fact the user's id, then you just need to take whatever's in `params[:id]` and [extract the integer id from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640819/extract-number-from-string-in-ruby).

So you'd have code like:

```
id = params[:id].scan(/\d+/).first
@user = User.find_by_profile_name(id)
```

If you wanted to change the name of your `:id` parameter, you could, but it's not required in order for it to work.

And if you wanted to go down the (more sensible) path of putting slashes between the parameters (for a url like `/105/john/smith`, or even `/105/johnsmith`) then you'd just change your routes to be either:

```
get '/:id/:first_name/:last_name', to: 'profile#show' # maps /105/john/smith
# or
get '/:id/:full_name', to: 'profile#show' # maps /105/johnsmith
```

And you could then leave the code in your controller exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

To find User ID out of the box:

In Users Show Controller: `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

In USERS SHOW.HTML.ERB: `<p><%- @user.id %><p>`